# Best way to constantly check value changes in the backend? Vue.js + Spring boot

Tags: rest, spring-boot, web-applications, vue.js, server

I have a single page application with frontend (Vue.js) and backend (Spring boot) parts. On the server side, there is a variable that I can assign using get request:

```
@GetMapping("/path")
public String getSomeVariable() {
    return someVariable;
}
```

Right now I send a request using axios every two seconds to check if the value changed.

```
setInterval(() => {
    axios.get('/path')
        .then(response => {
            //do some stuff with received value
        });
}, 2000);
```

I feel like that there is some better way to do this, that doesn't involve sending lots of requests. Can the spring boot app can somehow notify the client when the value changes?

Comment: You would usually use sockets for this, so I'm guessing [this is what you are looking for](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) and maybe [this article will help](https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-websocket-chat-example/)

Comment: Yeah, websockets is the way out.